# how do i combine the children of a node into one cell of a csv cell using elementtree in python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, csv, elementtree

this is the first time I'm really working with XML and i seem to be at a loss. i'm using elementtree in python and can parse the different nodes and even get them into a csv but i'm having trouble with the children (or sub nodes?) of < text >, which is < p >.

in looking at the documentation of elementtree:

```
for content in root.iter('p'):
    print content.text
```

gets me what i want, which is all the text from node < text >. however, when my code goes to write to the csv file, a new row is created for each < p >. great! but i want each < text > to be its own row with all the text from its children, < p >, in one cell per < text > row. i hope that makes sense (i almost confused myself...again).

here's my simple code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('the_example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('throw_it_all_in_this.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)   
    for content in root.iter('p'):
        print content.text
        writer.writerow([content.text])
```

and here's the the_example.xml i'm working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <example>
  <item>
   <source>some site</source>
   <subject>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</subject>
   <subjectcode>EN</subjectcode>
   <text>
    <p>
      Nam urna tellus, dignissim eu dolor nec, elementum posuere magna. Integer euismod ipsum 
      in lorem scelerisque efficitur.
    </p>
      <p>
        &amp;lt;
        <p>
          In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam sed iaculis diam, eget viverra 
          dolor. Vestibulum rutrum dolor. 
        </p>
        &amp;gt;
      </p>
    <p>
      Maecenas nisi dolor, pulvinar et diam vel, lacinia fringilla tellus. Quisque 
      feugiat id est in molestie. Aliquam eleifend lectus sed ex aliquam egestas. 
      Integer euismod ipsum in lorem scelerisque efficitur.
    </p>
    <p>
      Duis lobortis rutrum turpis, sit amet iaculis nibh pulvinar at. Cras euismod 
      semper nibh, quis maximus nisi ultrices nec. Curabitur sed nisl molestie, ullamcorper 
      dui nec, vestibulum mi. Proin quis efficitur turpis, quis aliquam purus. Curabitur 
      id faucibus lacus, posuere ullamcorper eros.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nam ullamcorper accumsan magna, quis bibendum nibh. Mauris finibus iaculis est, nec 
      consequat leo ultricies a. Etiam id sagittis mi. Mauris quis justo suscipit, placerat 
      est vitae, aliquet nunc. Aenean tincidunt leo erat, id dictum mi iaculis nec. Class 
      aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
    </p>
   </text>
  </item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate `text` tags, and find `p` tags inside the `text` tags. Combine them using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
....
for content in root.iter('text'):
    writer.writerow(['\n'.join(p.text for p in content.iter('p'))])
```

---

**UPDATE**

According to OP's commnet, to handle `TypeError`, `UnicodeEncodeError` OP should use the following:

```
writer.writerow(['\n'.join(p.text for p in content.iter('p')
                 if p.text is not None).encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: this works until i get a TypeError where there's a NoneType found. any idea on how i can get rid of that error?

Comment: i had to add to make a couple changes to get rid of the TypeError and the UnicodeEncodeError i was getting but this was the legit answer that got me there, thanks falsetru. here's my edits: writer.writerow(['\n'.join(p.text for p in content.iter('p') if p.text is not None).encode('utf-8')])

Comment: @Silas, Thank you for your feedback. I updated the answer accordingly.